# Grouping or filtering elements in a list by start and end date

Tags: java, arraylist, grouping

I've a List of Tasks which look like the following:

```
public Task(String content, Date start, Date end, String group, String title) {
    this.content = content;
    this.start = start;
    this.end = end;
    this.group = group;
    this.title = title;
}
```

Now I want to create a second list with all tasks with the same group and title grouped by date. This means I want one task for multiple tasks if they overlap in any way e.g. one tasks starts after another but ends later and so on. I addition I would like to modify the new element and adjust its end date.

I've tried iterating over a list sorted by start date and comparing all subsequent tasks, but with minor success. I feel stupid and would appreciate any help.

Thank you

Comment: This is a common problem with many implementations. Don't feel stupid, it's actually a pretty tricky problem with some "gotchas". This question might be helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32196549/combining-overlapping-date-ranges-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to start by by assuming you have created small lists where all the `group` and `name` fields are the same. An easy approach to doing this would be to use a two key dictionary or a map of a maps:

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<Task>>> 
//  Group       Title      Tasks
```

For each inner list you're going to want to reduce it to non-overlapping entries. Imagine your list of ranges could be represented like bellow:

```
0                     [=====]
1  [======]
2            [=]
3 [==]
4                         [=======]
5                [=====]
```

This looks like a mess, however, what would happen if we sorted it by the starting time?

```
3 [==]
1  [======]
2            [=]
5                [=====]
0                     [=====]
4                         [=======]
```

Here it is clear that there are three sections that are independent:

```
0 [=======]
1            [=]
2                [================]
```

To perform this reduction, you can iterate through the sorted list and add a new value to a result list whenever you discover a gap in the list. You make the new range by taking the earliest start time of the group and the latest end time. I found an [example on github by zac-xin](https://gist.github.com/zac-xin/4349436) which does just this. *(here `intervals` is a sorted list of `Interval` objects)*

> ```
> public class Interval {
>      int start;
>      int end;
>      Interval() { start = 0; end = 0; }
>      Interval(int s, int e) { start = s; end = e; }
> }
> ...
>
> Interval first = intervals.get(0);
> int start = first.start;
> int end = first.end;
>
> ArrayList<Interval> result = new ArrayList<Interval>();
>
> for(int i = 1; i < intervals.size(); i++){
>     Interval current = intervals.get(i);
>     if(current.start <= end){
>         end = Math.max(current.end, end);
>     }else{
>         result.add(new Interval(start, end));
>         start = current.start;
>         end = current.end;
>     }
> }
> ```

Once you've sorted each small list in you map of maps, you can combine them all into a single list.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I adopted the approach and now everything works as expected.

Answer (score -1):

That seems like a typical scenario of relational databases.
I think it is better to implement it with the help of databases e.g. using SQLite.

Doing this in object orientaded would be also possible but it is much easier using databases. :)